# Mesh not animating when parts are spawned from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So there is a prefab I obtained from [Toon Zombie Extended](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/toon-zombies-extended-pack-121996).
The prefab is made of multiple heads bodys and leg pieces, its meant for you to spawn it, delete the ones you dont want then create a new prefab.
[image: View]

I had the wise idea to try and spawn it, remove all the parts, then spawn them at random from a [script](https://pastebin.com/MsC00f9a). using standard Instantiation.

```
Instantiate(heads[head], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

problem is, it seems that parts spawned this way do not correctly identify the skeleton.

The whole object seems to be locked in place at 0,0,0 unable to animate or move.

[image: Img]

Is there some part of this that i'm not understanding? IFSO: how do I make this idea work?

Iv messaged the author, with no reply.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of animation, you need to keep the exact name. Maybe run your game and edit them in hierarchy just for testing.

On the other hand you may need to keep the bone-structure. You can see the skinned-mesh-renderer has a root bone defined as "Bip001 Pelvis" - everything else probably needs to be below this bone. Just compare with the original prefab.

Different ideas:

1. Leave all objects in the prefab, just disable the unused (`setActive(false)`)
2. Instead of spawning arms and legs, change the material, or even the mesh in the skinned mesh renderer, if needed.

Comment: Ok for idea 1, does setActive prevent it from updating and causing lag?
Different meshes for some parts.

Comment: disabled gameobjects are not updated, not rendered. There may be a very little overhead remaining. I wouldn't worry about it though.